# How to add one tier to this bootstrap listTree js

Tags: javascript

I am using https://bl.ocks.org/clayzermk1/3317341 listTree.js. This works for only two tier (parent-child). I want to increase the level to one more depth (parent-child-grandchild). I changed the template. I am not successful. Don't know where is the error.

expected result
parent
  child
    gchild

I am getting

parent
  child

data = [{"key": "parent", values:[{"key":"child", "values":[{"key":"grandchild"}]}]}]

Comment: from official site , it was mentioned as "I needed a simple plugin to build a two-tier collapsible list with checkboxes."

Comment: please share sample code which you have tried so far